# solve the equation $\sin (2z) = \cos^2( z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

$\sin(2z)=\cos^2(z)$ ..Im trying to solve this equation using  identities but i failed to get answer .. is using the fact that cos z and sin z are periodic of period $2\pi$ is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

$$2\sin z \cos z = \cos^2 z$$

Now, one set of solutions is obvious: the ones, where $\cos z=0$. The rest of them must satisfy the equation
$$\tan z = \frac12$$
which gives the second set of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin(2z)=\cos^2(z)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(2z)-\cos^2(z)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\cos(z)(\cos(z)-2\sin(z))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(z)(\cos(z)-2\sin(z))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(z)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space\cos(z)-2\sin(z)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(z)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space\cos(z)=2\sin(z)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(z)=0\space\space\vee\space\space\cot(z)=2$$

Comment: The "iff" in the middle of lines 5 & 6 should be replaced by "or" and some brackets added to separate the implied sentences. Good answer. You can save a lot of typing by using \iff  for logical equivalence.